# Setting up ansible playbook for a Nested Network Hierarchy

Tags: ssh, hierarchy, ansible

My hierarchy :

```
  HOST --->(ssh access)---> SERVER
```

The at the other end it is like:

```
  SERVER:
  --------->NODE1:
            --------->NODEA
            --------->NODEB
            --------->NODEC
            --------->NODED
```

The arrows show ssh access. The HOST has ssh access only to SERVER and I am running my playbook from HOST. It doesn't have ssh to the underlying machines. SERVER can ssh into NODE1. SERVER can't ssh into NODEA. I have tasks that has to be run on all these machines.

Once solution is to have a task like:

```
  - name: Do task in NODE1
    command: ssh user@NODE1 whoami
```

But this looks very inappropriate.

Another solution is to have 3 sets of playbooks.

1. Set 1 - ssh from HOST to SERVER and do the tasks. Have a task of downloading SET2.zip from a public url into SERVER.
2. Set 2 - This playbook can ssh into NODE1 from SERVER and do whatever is required there. Have a task of downloading SET3.zip from a public url into NODE1.
3. Set 3 - This can ssh to nodes A,B,C,D from NODE1.

Can you please suggest a better feasible alternative to this problem?

Note: I can't add ssh access from HOST to all the other nodes. If that was the case, this whole problem would not arise at all.

Comment: This looks like a typical jump server configuration (and rather non-related to SO). Where's the problem?

Comment: @techraf how do i move this to say serverfault?

Comment: Only moderators can do that, you could use "flag for moderator's attention" and explain you wish it to be migrated. But, frankly, questions written this way are not particularly well received on ServerFault.

Comment: @techraf if its not too much trouble, could you do an edit on the question, since you have understood the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typical case for a jump server configuration:

- Required settings in `~/.ssh/config` on SERVER:

  - if using OpenSSH version <7.3:

    ```
    Host NODEA
     ProxyCommand ssh NODE1 -W %h:%p
    ```
  - if using OpenSSH version >=7.3:

    ```
    Host NODEA
     ProxyJump NODE1
    ```
- Required settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on NODE1 (SSH daemon restart required after making changes):

  ```
  PermitTunnel yes
  AllowTcpForwarding yes
  ```
- Command to run on SERVER to connect to NODEA through NODE1:

  ```
  ssh NODEA
  ```

  As Ansible uses a regular SSH command, it will also work when run on the NODEA target.

---

You can then add another hop if you want to run Ansible locally on HOST. For example (>7.3):

```
Host NODEA
 ProxyJump SERVER, NODE1
```

---

You can further improve by `AgentForwarding` on HOST (and `AllowAgentForwarding yes` on NODE1) if you want to use the SSH key from HOST.

Also you can use wildcards in `~/.ssh/config` to match several hosts.